# Laravel Form not POSTing

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a form do a POST request, however it doesn't seem to be doing it... It comes up with the error

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

I'm not really sure why, I've been trying to do some googling but I haven't round anything. Here is my code.

Web.php

```
Route::post('/admin/products/view/{product}/edit', 'Admin\ProductController@edit')->name('admin.products.edit');
```

Form

```
<form method="POST"
    action="{{ route('admin.products.edit', ['product' => $product]) }}">
    @csrf
    <fieldset class="group-select">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="input-box name-firstname">
                    <label><em class="required">*</em> Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product[title]"
                        value="{{ $product->title }}" class="input-text required-entry"
                        required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box name-firstname">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product[name]" value="{{ $product->name }}"
                        class="input-text" disabled>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label><em class="required">*</em> Description</label>
                <textarea name="product[description]" class="input-text required-entry"
                    cols="5" rows="3" required>{{ $product->description }}
            </textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label><em class="required">*</em> Allergies</label>
                <textarea name="product[allergies]" class="input-text required-entry"
                    cols="5" rows="3" required>{{ $product->allergies }}
            </textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="input-box name-firstname">
                    <label><em class="required">*</em> Price £</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product[price]"
                        value="{{ $product->price }}" class="input-text required-entry"
                        required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box name-firstname">
                    <label>Brand</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" name="product[name]">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($brands as $brand)
                        <option value="{{$brand->id}}" @if($brand->id ==
                            $product->brand->id) selected @endif>{{ $brand->name}}
                        </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="submit" class="button submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I thought it might be something to do with the route, however even when manually putting the URL into the form it still has the same error. Also when I look at the data being sent its not posting the form data... I'm not sure if this is something to do with my form or maybe the controller. I would love some help on this!

Comment: Can you show all your form template and script if you're use ajax or something like it.

Comment: May be caused by not clearing the routing cache

`php artisan route:cache`

Comment: The full contents of the form tag would be a huge help.  Also, what do you see in the network tab of your browser's developer tools when submitting the form? Be sure to check 'preserve logs' to see the full record of activity through any reloads/redirects.

Comment: Well, I feel like a massive idiot. @JamesClarkDeveloper Thank you for your tip, I found out it was POSTing the data correctly, and then redirecting after. So I looked in my controller and found out why. I'd put the wrong route name and was routing it to its self... Haha thanks for the help though!

Comment: Glad it helped, and that you got it going!

Answer (score 0):

I've found out my problem, by putting on preserve logs and checking the network data I found out that it was redirecting after successfully posting the data. I checked my controller and saw that I'd used the wrong route name and was redirecting it to its self. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Why $product is necessary in the routes whie you're POST'ing the form?